# Best way for storing JWT Tokens in flutter?

Tags: flutter

Can anyone explain a good way of storing jwt tokens securely in flutter app

I am new for mobile app development and I think storing jwt tokens in SharedPreferences is not secure.

Answer (score 0):

Most of people just use shared preferences for this. If you don't want to use it there is this https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage that might help you